# Attaching image files to nodes programmatically in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is it possible to add an image to a node programmatically?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here is an example code using which you can use with node_save

```
$filepath = drupal_realpath('misc/druplicon.png');
  // Create managed File object and associate with Image field.
  $file = (object) array(
    'uid' => 1,
    'uri' => $filepath,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($filepath),
    'status' => 1,
  );

  // We save the file to the root of the files directory.
  $file = file_copy($file, 'public://');

  $node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array)$file;
`
```

Comment: +1. For whatever reason, I also had to add `'display' => 1` to the $file array, or else I got a constraint violation that field_doc_file_display was NULL. This was for a file rather than an image, which might be the difference.

Comment: There is a way to add Alt or Title to the image whit this method?

Comment: If the file is already referenced by a node, will I need to use file_copy to attach it to another node?

Comment: I also had to add "'display' => 1" to get this to work.

Comment: If you don't want to copy file and just use already existent file (image) you may use

$file = file_save($file);

instead of

$file = file_copy($file, 'public://');

Answer (score 32):

An easier way:

```
$filename = 'image.txt';
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.ibiblio.org/wm/paint/auth/gogh/gogh.white-house.jpg');
$file = file_save_data($image, 'public://' . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
$node->field_image = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array('0' => (array)$file));
```

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me:

```
$file_temp = file_get_contents('public://someimage.jpg');

// Saves a file to the specified destination and creates a database entry.
$file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, 'public://' . 'someimage.jpg', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

$node->field_page_image = array(
  'und' => array(
    0 => array(
      'fid' => $file_temp->fid,
      'filename' => $file_temp->filename,
      'filemime' => $file_temp->filemime,
      'uid' => 1,
      'uri' => $file_temp->uri,
      'status' => 1,
      'display' => 1
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Drupal community documentation gives slightly different way for doing this. https://www.drupal.org/node/2301425 . It says `file_usage_add($file, 'file', 'node', $node->nid);` must also be done while doing this.

Comment: You may also want to unlink the temporary file manually, if that is no longer needed. Otherwise it will accumulate to become a huge waste of storage space over time.

Comment: There is no temporary file in this case. The image is being downloaded to memory only, then stored in its target destination.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one extra bit that tripped me up for a while: this will attach the image to the node, and if you're adding the image then you're okay. However, if you're *updating* an image, and you care about displaying it on a page, then one extra step is needed before calling node_save():

```
image_path_flush($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']);
```

This will regenerate all of that image's styles.

Answer (score 2):

`$node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array)$file;`

I tried this with a multilingual site.  It failed fairly... but horribly.
I had to specify the language in question. Simply put, this worked instead:

`$node->field_image['en'][0] = (array)$file;`

Without it, the attached file was viewable in the 'view' screen but not in the 'edit' screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make it part of the $node object when you save it. Save it using node_save().

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$node = node_load(99);
$filename = 'image.txt';
chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.ibiblio.org/wm/paint/auth/gogh/gogh.white-house.jpg');
$file = file_save_data($image, 'public://' . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
$node->field_imagen_producto = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array('0' => (array)$file));
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just going to paste my solution here as well, I needed to create a new node, and upload an image programmatically.

```
$filepath = variable_get('file_public_path') . '/xmas_banner.jpg';
$file_temp = file_get_contents($filepath);
$file_temp = file_save_data($file_temp, file_default_scheme() . '://' .'xmas_banner_nl.jpg', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'carousel'; // custom content type
$node->title = 'XMAS NL';
$node->field_banner_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array) $file_temp;
$node->uid = 1;
$node->status = 0;
$node->active = 0;
$node->promote = 0;
node_save($node);
```