# Programmatically save image from external url - drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to create a node using last.fm.

```
$field = content_fields('field_my_image',"events"); //to get field
$validators = array_merge(filefield_widget_upload_validators($field), imagefield_widget_upload_validators($field)); //image validator
$files_path = filefield_widget_file_path($field); //save path
$src_path=$data->image[3]; // img url from last.fm eg: http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/502025.jpg
$file = field_file_save_file($src_path, $validators, $files_path, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);//save file
$nodenew->field_my_image = array(
                array(
                    'fid' => $file['fid'],
                    'title' => $file['filename'],
                    'filename' => $file['filename'],
                    'filepath' => $file['filepath'],
                    'filesize' => $file['filesize'],
                    'filemime' => $file['filemime'],
 ),
);//insert file details to node
```

Now the node is created, but no image and getting the message 'The selected file 502025.jpg could not be saved. The file is not a known image format.'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on finding an answer to your own question. Please post it as an answer ([it's fine to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), which makes it clear to other people that the question has an answer. You can also mark your own answer as accepted, if no other answer was more helpful.

Comment: Better answers over at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5129559/1229018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## update

Found the solution.

We need to save image to drupal folder first, by calling MODULENAME_save_image_local($url) in node creation function:

```
$src_path = MODULENAME_save_image_local($url);
```

add this function:

```
function MODULENAME_save_image_local($url) {
  $hash = md5($url);
  $dir = file_create_path('lastfm');
  if (!file_check_directory($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0775, FALSE);
  }
  $hash = md5($url);
  $cachepath = file_create_path('CUSTOMFOLDERNAME/'. $hash.'.jpg');
  if (!is_file($cachepath)) {
    $result = eventpig_lastfm_fetch($url, $cachepath);
    if (!$result) {
      //we couldn't get the file
      return drupal_not_found();
    }
  }
  return file_directory_path() .'/CUSTOMFOLDERNAME/'. $hash.'.jpg';
}
/**
 * Api function to fetch a url and save image locally
*/
function MODULENAME_fetch($url, $cachepath) {
  if (!$url) {
    return drupal_not_found();
  }
  $result = drupal_http_request($url);
  $code   = floor($result->code / 100) * 100;
  $types  = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
  if ($result->data && $code != 400 && $code != 500 && in_array($result->Content-Type, $types)) {
    $src = file_save_data($result->data, $cachepath);
  }
  else  {
    return drupal_not_found();
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Drupal 7 provides a function for much of what you are doing: system_retrieve_file().

There ought to be a file module function for saving a file to Drupal based on a URL, but at least the function does exist... just not where anyone will look.  You can use system_retrieve_file() with a third parameter of TRUE to create a managed file (calling file_save_data()).

Usage, a simpler example than Jav_Rock's but substantially the same, just skipping the hash path fanciness:

```
  $url = 'http://example.com/picture.png';
  $directory = file_build_uri('custom_directory');
  if (!file_prepare_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
    // If our directory doesn't exist and can't be created, use the default.
    $directory = NULL;
  }
  $file = system_retrieve_file($url, $directory, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it depends on url_fopen?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: after testing, its confirmed that with this method, we cant save external image url .. have to find a way to save external url image to drupal file directory first! any suggestion?

Comment: perhaps you can make a system call to wget? `<?php system('wget http://example.com/file > downloadfile')`