# Drupal 7 save user picture programmatically

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have found this script http://d.danylevskyi.com/node/7 which I have used as a starter for the below code.

The goal is to be able to save a user picture:

```
<?php
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$uid = 99;
$account = user_load($uid);

// get image information
$image_path = 'public://avatars/upload/b8f1e69e83aa12cdd3d2babfbcd1fe27_4.gif';
$image_info = image_get_info($image_path);

// create file object
$file = new StdClass();
$file->uid = $uid;
$file->uri = $image_path;
$file->filemime = $image_info['mime_type'];
$file->status = 0; // Yes! Set status to 0 in order to save temporary file.
$file->filesize = $image_info['file_size'];

// standard Drupal validators for user pictures
$validators = array(
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
    'file_validate_image_resolution' => array(variable_get('user_picture_dimensions', '85x85')),
    'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('user_picture_file_size', '30') * 1024),
);

// here all the magic :) 
$errors = file_validate($file, $validators);
if (empty($errors)) {

    file_save($file);
    $edit['picture'] = $file;
    user_save($account, $edit);
}
?>
```

A picture is created in sites/default/files/pictures/ with the name picture-99-1362753611.gif

Everything seems correct in the file_managed table except that:

1. the filename field is empty
2. the uri field shows public://avatars/upload/b8f1e69e83aa12cdd3d2babfbcd1fe27_4.gif
3. the status field is set to 0 (temporary)

The picture field in the users table gets updated with the fid of the above mentioned entry.

I would guess that the file_managed table should store the final file (in sites/default/pictures) instead of the original file info and that the users table should link to the one too.

Any idea how I can achieve that? I am quite new to the Drupal API. Thank you.

**Edit:**

I understand that I am giving the original file to the file_save and user_save functions. But which one actually creates the file in sites/default/pictures/ ?

Comment: [Attaching files to nodes programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129559/attaching-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-7)

Comment: I think there should be also `$edit['picture'] = $file->fid;` instead of `$edit['picture'] = $file;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following to your code:

```
$file->filename = drupal_basename($image_path);
$file->status   = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
$file = file_save($file);  // Use this instead of your current file_save
```

Does that help?

------------------ EDIT ------------------

If you want to save a copy of the file in a new location, you can replace the third line above with something like

```
// Save the file to the root of the files directory.
  $file = file_copy($file, 'public://');
```

Comment: Well. That kind of works but not as expected. Now, there is no file created in sites/default/pictures/ and the file_managed table still links to the file in sites/default/avatar/upload/. Now this leads to another question, should I be creating a file in the pictures folder or can I link to the original file? What's the proper way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Well, with the code above you are indeed linking to the original file, which is under avatars/upload... are you looking to copy the file to another location first?  If so, look at my updated answer.  :-)

Comment: Well, not especially after all. I was just asking myself if there is any difference between storing the user picture in that folder and  storing it in the default pictures folder / and to use the default naming.

Comment: I think that's up to you actually. I have lots of subfolders in my sites/default/files directly. In fact, when you're creating a new file field for your content types, Drupal asks you whether you want to store those files in a special /files/ subdirectory, so it's not unusual to do that. I have subfolders called /bios, /success_stories, etc that store images and files for my different content types in different subfolders. I'm sure other users don't do that, so it's a preference. As long as it's a subfolder of sites/default/files there shouldn't be a performance or other special difference.

Comment: The only thing is -- how did the files get in the /avatar subfolder to begin with?  Were they placed there by another module that may delete them at some point?

Comment: Hi Boriana, thank you for this useful information. The images are in this specific folder because I placed them there. I am migrating a huge phpBB forum to Drupal and the phpbb2drupal module fails importing the avatars from phpBB, so I am going to do it manually. My goal is to 1. Import phpBB users and 2. Update each user based on their e-mail address (unique) with the corresponding avatar (from a CSV file). So I should be fine with this solution. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I am running into another issue now. Here is the link to the new question if anyone can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336963/drupal-7-issue-with-programmatically-set-user-picture

Comment: Another question: how can I have this script to check if the user already has a user picture (an entry in the file_managed table), and delete it before trying to link the new picture? If I don't do that, then I get a PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry [...]