# Drupal 7 issue with programmatically set user picture

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am using a script to programmatically set the user picture in Drupal 7. The script is depicted here: [Drupal 7 save user picture programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297551/drupal-7-save-user-picture-programmatically).

The script works fine, but once the user picture has been set for a specific user, and if I try to delete that picture (as an admin or as the user himself) the server returns:

> Warning: unlink(/home/hkdepot/public_html/drupal_dev_4/sites/default/files/avatars/upload/b8f1e69e83aa12cdd3d2babfbcd1fe27_101.jpg): Permission denied in drupal_unlink() (line 2199 of /home/hkdepot/public_html/drupal_dev_4/includes/file.inc).

The file does not get deleted from the folder.

Is this anything I should worry about? Is that a right's issue when setting the picture? How do I deal with it?

Comment: Have you tried changing the permissions of `upload` directory? And also, you probably need to change the file permissions right after it has been uploaded.

Comment: The folder and its contents are set to 0775. Seems correct to me?

Comment: Are you sure the newly uploaded file has also those permissions? And is the file link correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "newly uploaded file"? The files in the avatars/upload/ folder were copied there manually. I am just linking them to the user account with the mentioned script, then using Drupal interface to **delete** the picture. I am not even trying to replace it.

Comment: The file link is correct too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 775 = rwxrwxr-x = **User**: *Read Write Execute*; **Group**: *Read Write Execute*; **World**: *Read, Execute*

It just means that the user that is trying to delete the file (likely www-data) is not the owner nor is it in the ownership group. So you either need to

1. Set the file permissions to `777`
2. Change the owner to the user who is deleteing
3. Add the user who is deleting to the group

Further reading:

- [Linux File Permission Bitmask](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+file+permission+bitmask&aq=f&oq=linux+file+permission+bitmask&aqs=chrome.0.57.5680j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- [How to change a file's owner and group in Linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+chown&aq=f&oq=linux+chown&aqs=chrome.0.57j5j0l2j62l2.1601j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Oh well, that worked. Although I thought it would work with 0775 since the owner of the files was the right user (on a VPS). Thanks anyway.