# file field programmatically PDOException _display in drupal7

Tags: php, file, pdo, field

[Attaching image files to nodes programmatically in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129559/attaching-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-7)

Hi,when I accroding this artical ,but met an pdo error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048
>   Column 'field_pr_quotation_file_display' cannot be null: INSERT INTO
>   {field_data_field_pr_quotation_file} (entity_type, entity_id,
>   revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_pr_quotation_file_fid,
>   field_pr_quotation_file_display, field_pr_quotation_file_description)
>   VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_8); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 136 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 249
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => purchase_request
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 24 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => ) in
>   field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 451 of
>   D:\www\Sites\pr\modules\field\modules\field_sql_storage\field_sql_storage.module).

Answer (score 0):

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69684/how-to-assign-value-from-one-file-field-to-another-programmatically according here ,I add display =1

```
$field_file = (array) $file;
$field_file['display'] = 1;

dpm($file,'field_pr_ref_quotation_file');
$node->field_pr_ref_quotation_file[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = $field_file;
```