# Programmatically adding default image to content type

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, default, content-type

Is there a way to add a "default image" file to a content type field, using features, a module or anything. The only way I have found so far is adding the image link to each node created without an image, but I was wondering if I could use something better and recommended

I found some related info here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129559/attaching-image-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-7).

-- EDIT --

To clarify, I do mean "a default image for a image field in a content type"

BUT, I am creating the content type using features and a the site using a script. I cannot use the form or anything related as I will potentially NEVER touch the site myself. I want to automate it all (:

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Default images won't come across in features, but you can use hook_field_default_fields_alter in a module to set the default image for that field.

Here's a discussion on it on the Drupal site:
https://drupal.org/node/1439136

comment 6 is a single use case which you could adapt for your field, while comment 7 is a more general solution which you can use for several fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please see the edits I just made though, I don't think the hook_form_alter works in this case right?

Comment: OK, I see. I'll updated my answer given the new info.

Comment: Hm thanks alot! But the hook never seems to be fired.. I added a watchdog statement in a test_field_default_fields_alter(&$fields){} - and - I tried creating a new content type, adding a field, saving each part of a field but nothing shows up..

Comment: Is this hook only part of drupalcommerce? https://www.google.com/search?q=hook_field_default_fields_alter only brings up http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!features!features.api.php/function/hook_field_default_fields_alter/DC

Comment: I think it might be part of features, have you got it enabled?

Comment: Yes, I just tried making sure features are on, and also tries creating a new content type through enabling a features... but no luck...

Comment: Have you created a module for your test_field_default_fields_alter(&$fields){} function?

Comment: Yep I have... and the only thing there is that hook... I made sure the module is properly registering using other hooks...

Answer (score 0):

I have been meaning to try something similar. Not sure exactly how it will work but the genral idea is as follows:

Create a rule - on insert of the content Type.

Have the rule set a data value which will be the image.

In my case I intend creating a new content type (ImageNodes) that will simply be a small, static set of nodes. Each ImageNodes node will consist of a key and an image.  When setting the data value in my rule I will inspect another field in the content being inserted and use that as a reference to the correct ImageNodes node.

This approach will allow me to attach default images to my content nodes on insert, to allow it to attach alternate images based on the contents of the inserted node.

Note, this approach can be implemented with the image being created as an entity reference (or similar), or alternatively the rules module is smart enough that I can copy the image field in the ImageNodes node to an image field in the content node being inserted.  Adding a condition to the rule will give you the ability to only inject the default image if none has been selected.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the info! I had thought of similar things but I wanted to know if I could avoid using a hook like node_insert or node_update to limit the amount of data I mess with to fields rather than nodes... but I guess it would be the same... ish

Answer (score 0):

The following code I adapted from [Features issue #1439136: *Support imagefield default images*](https://www.drupal.org/node/1439136) on drupal.org to work with Features API version 1.

It can easily be adapted though to work with Features API version 2 by changing the hook name as described in the notes and comments below.

This code sample should be added to your main module file `modulename.module`. I would suggest it is best to add to the features module where the entity and fields are defined. It should work with any Drupal fieldable entities. I've used it with users, nodes, taxonomy vocabularies, and field collection items.

To implement this in your own module, copy the code below and then:

1. Replace all occurrences of `modulename` with your module machine name.
2. Define all your field image defaults in the array returned by `modulename_images_fields_defaults()`.
3. Place your default images into your module path using a folder named `images`.

**Notes:**

- Field machine names can easily be located and copied from the Features API 1 file named `modulename.features.field.inc`.
- In Features API 2 the fields definition is split into `modulename.features.field_bases.inc` and `modulename.features.field_instances.inc`, so the hook also is renamed and can be used for either the field base or field instance:

  - `hook_field_default_field_bases_alter()`
  - `hook_field_default_field_instances_alter()`

**Code:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Define images for use as defaults in fields info.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function modulename_images_fields_defaults() {
  return array(
    'node-content_type_name-field_image' => 'default-image.png',
    'field_collection_item-field_collection_item_field_name-field_image' => 'default-image.png',
    'taxonomy_term-vocabulary_name-field_image' => 'default-image.png',
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_default_fields_alter().
 *
 * Alter field default values right before fields info is cached by features.
 *
 * @todo: Update to hook_field_default_field_bases_alter if Features upgraded.
 *
 * @param &$fields
 *   By reference. The fields that have been declared by another feature.
 */
function modulename_field_default_fields_alter(&$fields) {
  $source = drupal_get_path('module', 'modulename') . '/images';
  $destination = file_default_scheme() . '://default_images';

  $field_default_images = modulename_images_fields_defaults();

  foreach ($field_default_images as $field_name => $filename) {
    if (isset($fields[$field_name])) {
      _modulename_field_default_fields_alter_image(
        $fields[$field_name], $filename, $source, $destination
      );
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Alter image field default using managed source file.
 *
 * @param $field
 * @param $filename
 * @param $source_path
 *  The source folder path relative to the Drupal root where the image
 *  filename can be found.
 * @param $destination_uri
 *  The destination folder path as a stream wrapper uri ie. "scheme://target".
 */
function _modulename_field_default_fields_alter_image(&$field, $filename, $source_path, $destination_uri) {
  // See if a default image hasn't been set for this field yet
  if (!isset($field['field_config']['settings']['default_image'])
    || empty($field['field_config']['settings']['default_image'])
  ) {
    // Dynamically set the default image on the field
    $source_file_uri = "$source_path/$filename";

    // Check to see if managed file exists.
    $result = db_select('file_managed', 'f')
      ->fields('f', array('fid'))
      ->condition('f.uri', "$destination_uri/$filename")
      ->execute();

    $fid = $result->fetchField();

    // Simulate an upload of the default image.
    if (!$fid && file_exists($source_file_uri)) {
      $file = new stdClass;
      $file->filename = $filename;
      $file->timestamp = REQUEST_TIME;
      $file->uri = $source_file_uri;
      $file->filemime = file_get_mimetype($source_file_uri);
      $file->uid = 1;
      $file->status = 1;

      $file = file_copy($file, $destination_uri, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

      $fid = isset($file->fid) ? $file->fid : '';
    }

    $scheme = file_uri_scheme($destination_uri) ?: file_default_scheme();
    $field['field_config']['settings']['default_image'] = intval($fid);
    $field['field_config']['settings']['uri_scheme'] = $scheme;
  }
}
```